# Is it worth to use the default value of a member in a struct to save gas?

Tags: solidity, struct

Consider the following:

```
struct Activity {
    string name;
    uint8 durationInDays;
}
```

Most of my activities have a duration of 1 day. Is it worth to decrement one unit to save gas?

For example:

```
struct Activity {
    string name;
    uint8 durationInDaysMinusOne;
}
mapping ( uint => Activity) activities;

function storeActivity(uint uid, string name, uint8 durationInDays) {
   Activity storage activity = activities[uid];
   activity.name = name;

   require(durationInDays > 0);

   if(durationInDays > 1) {
      activity.durationInDaysMinusOne = durationInDays - 1;
   }
}
```

Does that `if` make sense to save gas?

Comment: Nice question but I think the entire struct might be initialized together and uint8 would take up 8 bits regardless. I'm not sure about that though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In my opinion*, this depends on how you weigh readability and optimization and possibly on who will pay for the gas.

There is a substantial saving avoiding an SSTORE (20,000 gas) when possible. Obviously, the `if` burns a little figuring out what to do.

There is a further optimization by replacing the `string` with a `bytes32`. In terms of style, if I were to do something like distorting a value in this way, then I would probably mark the mapping `private` and set up a getter to put the world back in order. Something like:

```
function getActivity(uint uid) public constant returns(bytes32, uint8) {
   return(activities[uid].name, activities[uid].durationInDaysMinusOne + 1);
}
```

Hope it helps.